When using the tkinter module, I am trying to make a spinbox for age, but it is changing my 10 to a 1. How do I fix it?
As said in the title, I am trying to restrict certain stuff on my gui based on age. I put:
def age_limit():
    age = spinbox.get()
    if age < "10":
        response.config(text="you're too young to be on here, kid.")
    else:
        response.config(text= "Go Ahead")

for 0 and 1, it says it correctly. However, when it hits 2, it says continue. I've tried making a variable equal to 10, but it just does the same. I've tried making it 100 to see if that was the problem, it was the same output. I was expecting it to say "your too young" up to 10, then say "Continue." for 11+.

You are probably trying to compare 2 strings but in python "2" < "10" is false. Try using if int(age) < 10:

@TheLizzard It worked! Thank you so much!
